# checking validity of given first order logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Apologies if this question is already posted.As it is hard to search $\LaTeX$ in google and first order logic in nothing without $\LaTeX$ .But i am sure i have different doubt than that of already posted one!

### Question

> Check if the given formula is valid or not.
>
> $1.\forall x \exists y P(x,y) \Rightarrow \exists y \forall x P(x,y)$
>
> $2.\forall x (P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x))\Rightarrow \left ( \forall x P(x) \Rightarrow \forall x Q(x) \right )$

### My Approach

> $1.\forall x \exists y P(x,y) \Rightarrow \exists y \forall x P(x,y)$

$x=\text{set of all boys}$

$y=\text{set of all girls}$

$P(x,y)=\text{x loves y}$

LHS=All boys loves some girls

RHS=some girl is loved by every boy.
Hence $LHS \rightarrow RHS $ is not valid as LHS=true and RHS=false

> $2.\forall x (P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x))\Rightarrow \left ( \forall x P(x) \Rightarrow \forall x Q(x) \right )$

$x=\text{set of natural numbers}$

$P(x)=x \text{which is multiple of }4$

$Q(x)= \text{Even natural numbers }$

LHS= $\forall x (P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x))$ which is always true.

RHS=$\left ( \forall x P(x) \Rightarrow \forall x Q(x) \right )$

which says that if everything is multiple of $4$ then everything is  even  which is not true.

Hence $LHS \rightarrow RHS $ is not valid as LHS=true and RHS=false

But i feel that $2$ is incorrect.
Please help!

Comment: Why you are using $\ne$ ? In order to check if a FOL formula is valid or not you have to consider possible interpretation; more specifically, for a formula with a *conditional* ($\Rightarrow$), if you can find an int where the LHS is TRUE and the RHS is FALSE, then you jave showed that the formula is **not** valid.

Comment: Applying it to your example 2 above, we have that (in the RHS) $\forall x P(x)$ is FALSE, because it is **not** true that every natural number is a multiple of $4$ and thus the RHS $\forall x P(x) \Rightarrow \forall x Q(x)$ is TRUE.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA by  $\neq$ i meant  $true \Rightarrow false $ only  ..thanks byw ...i updated it !

Comment: yes ! $False \Rightarrow False $ is true ..

Comment: So again: in 2 the LHS is TRUE while the RHS is FALSE $\Rightarrow$ FALSE, which is TRUE.

Comment: By the way, 2 is *valid*: try with a proof by contradiction: assume LHS TRUE and assume that RHS is FALSE, that means: $\forall x Px$ is TRUE and $\forall x Qx$ is FALSE, and see what happens.

Comment: thanks a lot..i got that